# Locust report /stats/requests data to other user interface

Tags: python, locust

I found out the Locust UI would fetch data from `http://my-locust-server/stats/requests` endpoint, and plot the chart. e.g. `Total request per Second`, `Response Time` and `Number of Users`.

I would like to send the `/stats/requests` data to another server for plotting purpose. How to do that in `locustfile.py` ?

Following codes won't work, just for demo purpose.

```py
from locust import HttpUser, task, events
import requests

class User(HttpUser):

    @task
    def scenario_01(self):
        self.client.get('/some_endpoint')

# ==========
# following codes won't work, will block the whole locust.
# ==========
import time
starttime = time.time()
while True:
    r = requests.get('http://my-locust-server/stats/requests')
    payload = r.json()
    requests.post('http://another-server-for-plotting', json=payload)
    time.sleep(5.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 5.0))
```

Now what I can think of is to run another program to fetch and report the data. But how to do that in one `locustfile.py`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this module is imported, the `while True` code will be evaluated and run forever. If you want that loop to run in the background, you could utilize the python [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) library. Put that while loop inside a callable function, and pass that function to a new Thread object and start the thread on import.

```
from locust import HttpUser, task, events
import requests

class User(HttpUser):

    @task
    def scenario_01(self):
        self.client.get('/some_endpoint')

def backgroundloop():
    while True:
        import time
        starttime = time.time()
        r = requests.get('http://my-locust-server/stats/requests')
        payload = r.json()
        requests.post('http://another-server-for-plotting', json=payload)
        time.sleep(5.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 5.0))

import threading
t = threading.Thread(target=backgroundloop)
t.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use Locust's [Event Hooks](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/extending-locust.html#event-hooks) to send data off directly without getting it from the web route. If you're running in distributed mode, [`worker_report`](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.event.Events.worker_report) would probably be best. Incomplete example:

```
from locust import events
import requests


@events.worker_report.add_listener
def send_data_off_somewhere(client_id, data):
    requests.post('http://another-server-for-plotting', json=data)
```

[locust-plugins](https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins#listeners) has good examples about how to use the events and even has a pre-built listener to ship data off directly to a timescale db.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Any ideas how frequently the `worker_report` fired ? @Solowalker

Comment: Every time the master receives a report from a worker. Each worker reports to master 2-3 seconds.